# Excel 2007 Ribbon combobox events

Tags: vba, combobox, excel-2007, ribbon

In office 2007 i created a combo box on the ribbon based on the material here 
[Source Page](http://roymacleanvba.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/308/)
The combo box works fine except, when i choose the same item in succession , in this case the onChange event does not fire. Is there some way to fix this. It seems onAction event does not work for ComboBox.

I really would appreciate any help...

Comment: does your XML have a macro tied to the OnChange or the OnAction event?  If it is tied to OnChange, choosing the same item in succession would not constitute a OnChange event, no?

Comment: @ Scott I don't think there is an OnAction for the combobox as OP says.  Maybe you could combine with a GetEnabled callback?  I assume you want to get the click that's not a change after the user has done something elsewhere in Excel?  Just guessing :).

Comment: Oh nevermind that last idea.  I confused "GetEnabled" with "GetFocus".

Comment: I do have a macro tied to onChange , the whole problem is it is not firing when the user chooses the same option twice.

Comment: I understand.  I think you may have to re-think the design.  It sounds like your using the combobox item like a button.  Maybe a dynamic menu ribbon item would work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems both combobox only has a 'onChange' event, so will not fire unless we change the selection.                Maybe a dropdow list may work as it has a 'onAction' event. As a work around i placed a dummy at the top of the list which can be used to change selection. I know this is a stupid work around  but it will have to do untill i check out the other options like a Dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `oRibbonCMM.InvalidateControl ("yourcontrolID")` just after you select the item, I haven't tested this but I think it should work